# PHP File Exists not working / Error

Tags: php

I am having an issue with PHP's file_exists(). I've been through the manual and read a bunch of other posts. I seem to be missing something as my code cannot retrieve my file. Can anyone offer some insight?

```
echo $large_image_location;
```

outputs:     images/portfolio/DRAWINGS/DRAWING_1.jpg

The following produces "no" as it cannot find the file:

```
if (file_exists($large_image_location)){
  echo "yes";}
else{
  echo "no";
}
```

The following produces yes:

```
if (file_exists("images/portfolio/DRAWINGS/DRAWING_1.jpg")){
  echo "yes";}
else{
  echo "no";
}
```

Can anyone help (and tell me why)? I need to use dynamic variables…

Thanks,

-Allan

Comment: The value of the variable is not what you think it is.  Do a `var_dump($large_image_location);` and post the *Exact* results here.

Comment: What's the code you used to set the value of $large_image_location?

Comment: If `$large_image_location` does indeed contain `"images/portfolio/DRAWINGS/DRAWING_1.jpg"` then this is impossible. Use `var_dump` or similar and check what its actual contents are.

Comment: `$upload_path` is derived from a form input. The user selects a category and based on that  category the variable (and therefore directory) is set. The images in the directory are sequential (0001,0002,etc.) `$large_image_name` is derived from counting the number of images in the directory and adding 1 to it. `$Session['user_file_ext]` is set during image upload and is usually (and in this case) '.jpg' Thanks again for your suggestions!

Comment: @Andrea here's what var_dump gives me: string(39) "images/portfolio/DRAWINGS/DRAWING_1.jpg"

Comment: @cale_b here's what var_dump gives me: string(39) "images/portfolio/DRAWINGS/DRAWING_1.jpg"

Comment: @tokamak `$upload_path` is derived from a form input. The user selects a category and based on that category the variable (and therefore directory) is set. The images in the directory are sequential (0001,0002,etc.) `$large_image_name` is derived from counting the number of images in the directory and adding 1 to it. `$Session['user_file_ext]` is set during image upload and is usually (and in this case) '.jpg' Thanks again for your suggestions! – user3853379 39 mins ago

Comment: @tokamak here's the code to produce the variable `$large_image_location = $upload_path . $large_image_name . $_SESSION['user_file_ext'];`

Comment: What do you get if you try 'echo $large_image_location == "images/portfolio/DRAWINGS/DRAWING_1.jpg";' ?

Comment: @tokamak no output shows on the screen

Comment: Maybe it'd be better to wrap that up into an if statement: `if ($large_image_location == "images/portfolio/DRAWINGS/DRAWING_1.jpg") { echo "true"; } else { echo "false"; }`

Comment: Could it be that the uploaded file is being stored in a temporary uploads folder (this is sometimes what the webserver does) while you do the file_exists test on it with the variable input, then it's moved where you expect it to be before the test using the hard-coded string?

Comment: @tokamak I think I have this figured out. Thanks to you and the others for your help. It looks like my auto-increment of the file name is the trouble. At the point where I was testing my output it was the correct value. The page then calls itself again to allow the user to make a thumbnail from the uploaded image and a new filename+1 is built. when the fileexists test is run, the file really isn't there. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess as to what's happening: at the point you're testing whether the file exists, it's still residing in the temporary directory on the webserver, assuming you're using the POST method.
You can test it in that temp location by using the file location given by: `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']`

Read up on it here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

> Files will, by default be stored in the server's default temporary directory...

Getting `true` back from moving the file from the temp location to the final resting place you pick is a 2-birds-with-1-stone way of checking the file's existence:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $large_image_location)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else { // File doesn't exist, could not be moved, this is a problem 
}
```

Comment: thanks again. This thinking spurred me to test my missing variable in a different way. I hardcoded it right before the file_exists test and the page worked. This helped me back trace the trouble my autoincrement was causing (see above). Thank you again! ~Allan

Comment: Glad I helped in a small way even though that wasn't the solution :)

Answer (score -1):

Try instead

```
if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$large_image_location)){
   echo "yes";}
else{
   echo "no";
}
```

Comment: This also results in a no